# Output mongoDB aggregation result with Jade

Tags: mongodb, express, pug

I'm trying to get a random object from my database to be displayed on the website. When I comment out the Jade portion listed below, nothing breaks. When I uncomment it I get:

> TypeError: C:\Users\Malachi\Sandbox\CEC\myapp\views\layout.jade:63

```
   61|         .office-devide   
   62|           h2 Patient Reviews  
>> 63|             each user in userreviews  
   64|               ul  
   65|                 li= user.reviewfirstname  
   66|                 li= user.reviewlastname
```

> Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I've looked around at a few other similar problems here and can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated. If you require additional information let me know. Thanks!

**Express code**

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  var db = req.db;
  var collection = db.get('userreviews');
  collection.aggregate( [ {sample: { size: 3} } ] ,function(e,docs){
    res.render('index', {
    title: 'Reviews',
    "userreviews" : docs
    });
  });
});
```

**Jade code**

```
h2 Patient Reviews
  each user in userreviews
    ul
      li= user.reviewfirstname
      li= user.reviewlastname
      li= user.reviewsite
      li= user.reviewdate
      li= user.reviewtext
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `toArray` like so

```
collection.aggregate([ {$sample: { size: 3} }]).toArray(function(e,docs) {
    res.render('index', {
      title: 'Reviews',
      userreviews : docs
    });
});
```

In addition you have to use [$sample](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sample/), i.e. add a '$' to your stage operator.

Comment: That didn't work. Jade is still throwing "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined."

Comment: Also, when I commented out the jade each block I got "collection.aggregate(...).toArray is not a function"